# Form validation not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I'm trying a form validation in jQuery but it's not working the way I'm doing it. I want the border of the input to turn red if the input area is empty when I focus out.

OR

I want to add the bootstrap class called "has-danger", which turns the border and the background red-ish, if the input area is empty.

Here's the code:

```
<fieldset class="form-group"> <br>
    <label for="name">Name</label> <br><br>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name"> <br>
</fieldset>
```

jQuery code 1:

```
$("#name").blur(function() {
    if((this).val() == "" ) {
        $(this).addClass("has-danger");
    }
});
```

jQuery code 2:

```
$("#name").blur(function() {
    if((this).val() == "" ) {
        $(this).css("border", "solid 1px red");
    }
```

Comment: a) Welcome to Stack Overflow. b) Don't put code in images. c) Don't link those images from an external hosting. d) Use the code formatting to paste the code directly into the question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you include text of `html` , `javascript` at Question, instead links to images of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the `$` just before `(this)` in your `if` statement

Note: I've added an `else` for when the field is filled the `border` gets removed

```js
$("#name").blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    $(this).css("border", "solid 1px red");
  } else {
    $(this).css("border", "");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: have you tested my snippet? it works ( you have also spaces in html)

Comment: Yes I have. The reason I have spaces in my html is because stackoverflow doesn't show the exact html code if I dont add the spaces in the tags

Comment: about the spaces you can use code block, I fixed your question for you, regarding the answer, it turns red when it is empty, what else you want?

Comment: It is working now, strangely when I copied your jquery snippet in my code editor. It wasn't when I added the $ before "this". Thanks for your help